# Searching transaction in Mint by text in notes

Tags: mint.com

In Mint, when using the search bar in the transactions tab, any text I use gets matched either to categories, description or tags and even date or amounts if I use numbers, but I can't find a way to search for text in the notes.

Does anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Try with the following in the search box
notes:text that is being searched

Comment: It's funny this question was closed, but it is seriously SO helpful! Thank you for this answer!

Comment: Same here - found it super helpful. I can see how/why it's 'off-topic', but an argument could certainly be made that a question about filtering and searching financial transactions would fit in Personal Finance & Money Stack Exchange...

Comment: Aaaand then Intuit changed everything about the interface, and this feature no longer works… Thanks Intuit! 